# Perform side effect after Json Patch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, json-patch

Currently have an asp.net web api and implementing JSON Patch using `AspNetCore.JsonPatch` and want to perform a side effect if a certain action is done via Json patch?

E.g. patch request to update an array is done then triggers another function to be called to update a database.

Is there anything built in to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in can do it, But you can use `automapper` to achieve it. Refer to this demo:

```
[HttpPatch("update/{id}")]
public Person Patch(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<PersonDTO> personPatch)
{
    // Get our original person object from the database.
    PersonDatabase personDatabase = dbcontext.xx.GetById(id); 

    //Use Automapper to map that to our DTO object. 
    PersonDTO personDTO = _mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(personDatabase); 
    
    //Apply the patch to that DTO. 
    personPatch.ApplyTo(personDTO); 
    
    //Use automapper to map the DTO back ontop of the database object.      
    _mapper.Map(personDTO, personDatabase); 

    //Update our person in the database. 
    dbcontext.xx.Update(personDatabase); 

    return personDTO;
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way I've found so far, hope it can help you.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm thinking, basically thinking if we update "Name" on the person object when patching for example can we then trigger a side effect function. If that makes sense.

Comment: I can get your point, But after I searching alot of information about this, I don't find  any method similar to `trigger a side effect function` so far.

Comment: Yeah me neither sadly going to have to be a custom implementation